# Change OpenStack controller public name

Tags: openstack

Currently all my OpenStack services know the controller as `controller` (its hostname actually). But I wanna expose my OpenStack deployment to the public so I have to replace it with controller's valid IP.

How could I edit controller public name (IP)?

I read on somewhere I have to edit all OpenStack services files in `/etc` that contains `http://controller...` in addition to edit stored values in database (I don't know which tables). Is there any easier way (maybe a builtin app) to do it? Does this name changing have side-effects?